# Ubuntu Daily apt download rebooted the system

Tags: apt, updates, reboot

/var/log/syslog

```
Jan 14 02:17:36 server systemd[1]: Started Session 8012 of user root.
Jan 14 02:19:09 server systemd[1]: Started Session 8013 of user root.
Jan 14 02:19:58 server systemd[1]: session-8013.scope: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:20:20 server systemd[1]: Started Session 8014 of user root.
Jan 14 02:24:38 server systemd[1]: Starting Update APT News...
Jan 14 02:24:38 server systemd[1]: Starting Update the local ESM caches...
Jan 14 02:24:38 server systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:24:38 server systemd[1]: Finished Update APT News.
Jan 14 02:24:39 server systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:24:39 server systemd[1]: Finished Update the local ESM caches.
Jan 14 02:34:57 server systemd[1]: Starting Update APT News...
Jan 14 02:34:57 server systemd[1]: Starting Update the local ESM caches...
Jan 14 02:34:57 server systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:34:57 server systemd[1]: Finished Update APT News.
Jan 14 02:34:58 server systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:34:58 server systemd[1]: Finished Update the local ESM caches.
Jan 14 02:35:53 server systemd[1]: Starting Update APT News...
Jan 14 02:35:53 server systemd[1]: Starting Update the local ESM caches...
Jan 14 02:35:53 server systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:35:53 server systemd[1]: Finished Update APT News.
Jan 14 02:35:53 server systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:35:53 server systemd[1]: Finished Update the local ESM caches.
Jan 14 02:36:13 server dbus-daemon[640]: [system] Reloaded configuration
Jan 14 02:36:13 server dbus-daemon[640]: message repeated 8 times: [ [system] Reloaded configuration]
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: Started Reminder for degraded MD arrays.
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: mdmonitor-oneshot.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:36:14 server systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt download activities.
Jan 14 02:36:15 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:36:15 server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in MD array scrubbing - continuation being skipped.
Jan 14 02:36:25 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:36:25 server systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Jan 14 02:36:25 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:36:26 server systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:36:26 server systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Jan 14 02:37:07 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:37:07 server systemd[1]: Stopping Ripple Daemon...
Jan 14 02:37:36 server systemd[1]: rippled.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:37:36 server systemd[1]: Stopped Ripple Daemon.
Jan 14 02:37:36 server systemd[1]: Started Ripple Daemon.
Jan 14 02:37:36 server rippled[1426207]: 2024-Jan-14 01:37:36.407734732 UTC JobQueue:NFO Using 10  threads
Jan 14 02:37:36 server rippled[1426207]: 2024-Jan-14 01:37:36.495104353 UTC LedgerConsensus:NFO Consensus engine started (cookie: 8143542113068599825)
Jan 14 02:37:36 server rippled[1426207]: 2024-Jan-14 01:37:36.500503251 UTC Application:NFO Process starting: rippled-2.0.0, Instance Cookie: 11451704855547504397
Jan 14 02:37:37 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:37:37 server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Ubuntu Pro Timer for running repeated jobs being skipped.
Jan 14 02:37:37 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:37:37 server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Ubuntu Pro Background Auto Attach being skipped.
Jan 14 02:37:38 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: message repeated 2 times: [ Reloading.]
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: ssh.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: ssh.service: Found left-over process 1426011 (sshd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: ssh.service: Found left-over process 1426011 (sshd) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jan 14 02:37:39 server dbus-daemon[640]: [system] Reloaded configuration
Jan 14 03:10:01 server CRON[1434546]: (root) CMD (test -e /run/systemd/system || SERVICE_MODE=1 /sbin/e2scrub_all -A -r)
Jan 14 03:11:12 server systemd[1]: Starting Online ext4 Metadata Check for All Filesystems...
Jan 14 03:11:12 server systemd[1]: e2scrub_all.service: Succeeded.
Jan 14 03:11:12 server systemd[1]: Finished Online ext4 Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
Jan 14 03:17:01 server CRON[1434904]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jan 14 03:22:05 server systemd[1]: Stopping Session 1 of user root.
Jan 14 03:23:29 server systemd-sysctl[419]: Not setting net/ipv4/conf/all/promote_secondaries (explicit setting exists).
Jan 14 03:23:29 server kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-166-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-011) (gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)) #183-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 2 11:28:33 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-166.183-generic 5.4.252)
```

It then restarts..

[/var/log/dpkg.log](https://justpaste.it/9x9xn)

So is it normal that it may reboot server which is actually undesired to happen?

**Current version**: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-169-generic x86_64)

**UPDATE:**

/var/log/apt/history.log

```
Start-Date: 2024-01-14  02:24:56
Commandline: apt install libc6
Upgrade: libc6-dev:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.12, 2.31-0ubuntu9.14), libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.12, 2.31-0ubuntu9.14), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.12, 2.31-0ubuntu9.14)
End-Date: 2024-01-14  02:24:58

Start-Date: 2024-01-14  02:36:07
Commandline: apt-get upgrade -y
Upgrade: perl-base:amd64 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.4, 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.5), netplan.io:amd64 (0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2, 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.4), libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.40.0-1ubuntu0.1, 1.40.0-1ubuntu0.2), intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20230808.0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 3.20231114.0ubuntu0.20.04.1), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:20.04.10.11, 1:20.04.10.18), mongodb-mongosh:amd64 (2.0.2, 2.1.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-166.183, 5.4.0-169.187), vim-common:amd64 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.20, 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.21), libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.20, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.21), libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.3, 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.4), libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9), libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.6, 2.34-6ubuntu1.7), libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.5, 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.6), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (29.4~20.04, 30~20.04), binutils:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.6, 2.34-6ubuntu1.7), perl-modules-5.30:amd64 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.4, 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.5), python3.8:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9), openssh-sftp-server:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.9, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11), locales:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.12, 2.31-0ubuntu9.14), mongodb-database-tools:amd64 (100.9.1, 100.9.4), libapparmor1:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.2, 2.13.3-7ubuntu5.3), libperl5.30:amd64 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.4, 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.5), binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.6, 2.34-6ubuntu1.7), libtiff5:amd64 (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.10, 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.11), libc-bin:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.12, 2.31-0ubuntu9.14), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:20.04.10.11, 1:20.04.10.18), python3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9), tar:amd64 (1.30+dfsg-7ubuntu0.20.04.3, 1.30+dfsg-7ubuntu0.20.04.4), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.43ubuntu1.14, 0.43ubuntu1.15), libssh-gcrypt-4:amd64 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.3, 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.4), xxd:amd64 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.20, 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.21), openssh-server:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.9, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11), openssh-client:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.9, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.11), iputils-ping:amd64 (3:20190709-3, 3:20190709-3ubuntu1), binutils-common:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.6, 2.34-6ubuntu1.7), libnetplan0:amd64 (0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2, 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.4), libbinutils:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.6, 2.34-6ubuntu1.7), libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.8, 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.9), libgnutls30:amd64 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.8, 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.9), perl:amd64 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.4, 5.30.0-9ubuntu0.5), vim-tiny:amd64 (2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.20, 2:8.1.2269-1ubuntu5.21), rippled:amd64 (1.12.0-1, 2.0.0-1), curl:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.20, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.21), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.20, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.21), libctf0:amd64 (2.34-6ubuntu1.6, 2.34-6ubuntu1.7)
End-Date: 2024-01-14  02:37:49

Start-Date: 2024-01-14  04:05:46
Commandline: apt upgrade libc6
Install: linux-image-5.4.0-169-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-169.187, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-169-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-169.187, automatic), linux-modules-5.4.0-169-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-169.187, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.166.163, 5.4.0.169.167)
End-Date: 2024-01-14  04:06:05
```

/var/log/auth.log

```
Jan 14 03:19:09 NFT-backend sshd[1435023]: Connection closed by invalid user pi 82.64.25.86 port 41162 [preauth]
Jan 14 03:23:29 NFT-backend sshd[677]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 14 03:23:29 NFT-backend sshd[677]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 14 03:23:29 NFT-backend systemd-logind[640]: New seat seat0.
Jan 14 03:23:29 NFT-backend systemd-logind[640]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Jan 14 03:23:29 NFT-backend systemd-logind[640]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Jan 14 03:23:40 NFT-backend sshd[940]: Accepted password for root from 185.108.128.54 port 9448 ssh2
Jan 14 03:23:40 NFT-backend sshd[940]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 14 03:23:40 NFT-backend systemd-logind[640]: New session 1 of user root.
Jan 14 03:23:40 NFT-backend systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 14 03:24:12 NFT-backend sshd[1312]: Invalid user admin from 175.206.47.218 port 61410
```

Comment: What does pat's logs say about it? It should me the actual command that was executed

Comment: Your output: `Commandline: apt-get remove libc6`. Looks like human entered that command. Looks like a human ignored the screenful of proposed removals and agreed to it. Wrong format for automated.

Comment: I have found "8953  apt-get remove libc6" in the recent history log. Seems like indeed a college tried to solve some issues...

Comment: That colleague owes you a lunch for your trouble. And a second lunch for not admitting immediately, leaving the frustration and troubleshooting to you. That's the kind of activity that loses folks admin permissions.

Comment: It is possible to set up unattended  upgrades to reboot the system automatically when required, but that is not the default configuration.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this is doing, and why it would fix the problem? I'm not sure why making this particular file as executable would prevent the reboot behavior being described in the initial question.

Comment: it not making exe its making not executible. its possibly the script that is run to reboot after upgradeing.